# i need to know what to look at as an example...

Tags: navigation, android-viewpager, adapter

I've been stuck for a while now trying to use a viewpager for my apication navigation. all I want is the initial pages shown in my viewpagwr (which is a list of cardviews) to be clickable and each card will then disay a new fullscreen page with more information.

I am only. Trying to load text and images.

I have managed to create the viewpager and populate it (each card) with an image and 2 text views. I want to use the same data as page1 for page2.

I have my card click set but it only opens the blank template for page2. I can't figure out how to use my data to populate it (page2).

Does anyone have an example of this style of navigation they could link me to?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find an example of exactly what I am trying to imitate in a github project entitled "cheese square".